# How to get ETag value for items returned by CreateItemQuery

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm using V3 (preview) of [Cosmos DB SDK for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3).

When getting an item using **ReadItemAsync** the result has ETag available from the **CosmosItemResponse** wrapper of the entity object [**SalesOrder**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/CodeSamples/Shared/SalesOrder.cs):

```cs
CosmosItemResponse<SalesOrder> itemResponse = 
    await container.Items.ReadItemAsync<SalesOrder>(
        partitionKey: "Account1",
        id: "SalesOrder1");
Console.WriteLine("ETag of read item - {0}", itemResponse.ETag);
```

But when getting an item using **CreateItemQuery** (passing a SQL), the result is put in **CosmosQueryResponse** containing only the array of items instead of an array of **CosmosItemResponse**, so I cannot get the ETag of each item. Definition of entity **Family** is at [the end of this file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/CodeSamples/Queries/Program.cs).

```cs
var query = new CosmosSqlQueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM Families f WHERE f.id = @id AND f.Address.City = @city")
    .UseParameter("@id", "AndersonFamily")
    .UseParameter("@city", "Seattle");
List<Family> results = new List<Family>();
var resultSetIterator = container.Items.CreateItemQuery<Family>(query, partitionKey: "Anderson");
while (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults) {
    results.AddRange((await resultSetIterator.FetchNextSetAsync()));
}
```

I cannot find other ways to get items using SQL so the ETag is returned with the item itself.  Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the ETag and other system attributes have already been added.  I made my entity objects derived from a custom class that has CosmosDB system attributes such as below

```cs
    public class CosmosDBEntity
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }   // for CosmosDB required id, initialize with Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_etag")]
        public string ETag { internal get; set; }   // for CosmosDB so we can get the ETag but doesn't get serialized to CosmosDB
    }
```